# firefox image display issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am working on creating a website with a background that transitions with a fade.  I have an issue with display when viewing with Firefox.  The site loads fine and cycles through the images, when the point comes for it to return to the first image it resizes to a tiny pic in the top left corner.  This does not happen on any other browsers, and it does not happen with all of the images in the cycle.  If I refresh the page the problem is fixed and the sizing issue goes.  I have tried from other computers and the problem is consistent.  A version of the site can be seen http://www.rhys-williams.webspace.virginmedia.com/  Any help with this issue would be a big help thanks.

---

***SOLVED***

I have resolved this problem.  The issue is caused by the cycle changing quicker than the image loads.  I added a second to the display time and it now displays fine :)

Comment: Ipad flickers really bad. Consider jquery 1.10

Answer (score 0):

Remove **div** from this line -> so your code will look like:

```
<div id="slideshowContainer"  class="slideshow">
```

I guess that firefox was confused because of it.

Edit: Also, there are few unclosed tags (html errors), but i think this was the main reason of problems. Also, document has no valid declaration... fix these things, and then try... i have tested locally, with base href, and all works fine?

Hm -> please try to remove this, too:  **next:   '.slideshow'**

next option should have selector for next button, if i remember well...

Comment: Thanks, I have tried fixing that typo but the problem still exists.  I will sort the unclosed tags and declaration as well and try again.

Comment: And, maybe - try to set images width and height ->or use window.load: load, rather than document.ready. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ Somehow - images sizes aren't properly calculated when page loads first time. -> 24px24px (checked in dev toolbar in ff) But... first of all - update jquery version - in IE10 problems are even bigger than in FF... :)

Comment: it seems to be the image size that is the problem its 1.7mb I have compressed an image and it works fine (apart from the image now looks bad)